# USB-C Pogo Pin Coupler Troubleshooting

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, usb, usb-c, pogo-pins

I've been working on this project for a while now and have hit a bit of a wall.

I've been designing a magnetic cable coupler for a automotive device (Comma3X). The device communicates with the car via CAN over a custom-pinned USB-C cable. I assumed this coupler wouldnt be too hard to figure out. After all, it'd just be extending the connection through Pogo pins and traces, right...?

I used KiCad for my design, followed the cable requirements, routed the USB connections to the correct pin/pad, error checked, then ordered.

Here is the pin-out of the connection I'm following:

[image: Comma3X USB-C Pin-out Diagram]

Here is my KiCad schematic:

[image: Crop of a KiCad schematic.]

Male PCB:

[image: KiCad PCB overview/design]

Female PCB:

[image: KiCad PCB overview/design]

The male and female pads are flipped/mirrored due to their physical orientation. They mate like so:

[image: 3D representation of the connectors assembled.]

I have since received the PCB designs and assembled them. I used a USB cable tester to check that there were no shorts, and that all connections had continuity.

However, upon using the coupler I noticed that I wasnt getting a proper connection. Power works fine, but the data lines don't seem to be communicating correctly.

They included a USB-C coupler with the unit, some amazon special: [AGVEE USB-C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B093QDXZSS)

I've since ordered a pack and disassembled one of them, hoping to spot the difference in my design. Unsurprisingly it was essentially the same thing. The only notable difference was the lack of pins and the much shorter traces.

I know this magnetic pogo pin idea is possible as other users have created such boards and got them to work. I'm quite stumped as to what I'm doing wrong. I sure hope its something obvious that my inexperience has missed! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Clarify USB wording.

Comment: @vir The confusing part of this question is he's not designing a USB coupler, he's designing a (presumably proprietary) OBD over USB-C coupler.

Comment: Your PCB shows no USB connections so it must not be for an USB device? There are CAN buses. Are the CAN buses swapped when you connect your adapters? Did you use standard fully connected Type-C cables that include all the pairs, instead of using only USB2 pairs?

Comment: Also, how did you check for errors? That is called an OBD-C cable. Are they not using even Type-C USB cables? Do they use custom wiring that makes it incompatible with Type-C cable?

Comment: @user71659 Yeah my word choice wasnt the greatest, sorry about that. The only thing that is USB about this coupler is that it uses the USB-C form factor. The specs of the Comma3X (C3X) call for a cable that is at least capable of USB 3.1 Gen. 2 speeds, though I believe thats just to ensure that is a fully populated 24P connector.

Comment: @Justme Correct, this isnt a USB device, only the connector uses the USB-C form factor. I'll edit the question to clarify. The CAN buses are swapped when the adapter is connected, making the trace connect directly from pin to pin. The OEM cable is a populated 18P cable, confirmed via my tester (The tester I got is some amazon thing, just has little diodes that light up if the wire has continuity). The wiring is custom, as the provided cables dont work with any other USB-C devices that I've tested.

Comment: @Justme In terms of error checking: The only error checking I did was making sure there were no shorts. I dont really know of a good way to check data integrity across the pins. After looking through some of the unit's logs I've found that on boot some systems communicate correctly while others are either not present or skipped. I should ask around and see if I can get more details on how exactly the unit communicates over these lines.

Comment: Does a standard USB-C cable (the ones with all pins connected) work between the units? They do swap some pins but not all. And if this device doesn't use the CC pins, it should work; USB-C cables may have electronics on them and connect only one. Also, why would anyone want dangerous mag adapters for their devices? These bypass all the hotpluggability features of USB connectors, as they make sure the pins connect in the right order so no damage can happen. Your mag adapter might connect supply first, then a data pin, and that's enough a reason to not use non-USB connectors for USB.

Comment: @Justme Yes I've used a generic USB-C 24P cable and it works fine. I want a mag adapter for ease of use removing the unit. It sits attached to the windshield and can get quite hot if left exposed, especially in summer. I also like to put up a sun-screen in my car to keep it cool but the unit is in the way. It'd also be nice to just take it down when parked, as the unit itself looks and is expensive. Your critique makes sense though, I never really thought of that being an issue. Perhaps I could negate that effect by using long data pins coupled with short power pins to ensure connection order.

Comment: This first screamed HF signal integrity issues to me, but then I checked that CAN usually doesn't run higher than 1 MHz so not sure. Still, a couple of things:
The data lines are very close to each other and differential pairs are not done properly (they are supposed to follow the same path for as long as possible), but again the frequency isn't that high so this might not be the issue. Having the tracks so close and also in a loop is more likely to cause problems. Also, adding a ground plane on both sides of the PCB wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @DELTA12 In the past I've used autorouting and for this one I just did what I know so I used it again. Probably not the best move for data sensitive applications, now I know! I'll re-do the traces to neaten them up. When you say in a loop, you mean the lower left hand portion of the male PCB, right? That massive collection of traces?